# Setting the height on a border in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a left/right border on a list to create a separation effect.
Ex: `Link1` | `Link2` | `...`

I want the lines on the border to be a bit shorter than the total height of the object -- maybe 50% of the total height and centered vertically. However, they are 100% of height. How can I set a height on a border and center it vertically?

Thanks!

```
<ul class="nav pull-right" style="line-height:30px;">
    <li class="dropdown pull-right" style="line-height:20px;border-left: 1px solid #e3e3e3;border-right: 1px solid #e3e3e3;">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
           {% if notice_unseen_count %} <span class="badge badge-warning" style="line-height:15px;">{{ notice_unseen_count }}</span>{% else %}<span class="badge" style="line-height:15px;">0</span>{% endif %}
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="{% url messages_inbox %}">Inbox</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="{% url invitations %}">Invitations</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="{% url notification_notices %}">All Notifications</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: Use a background image instead?

Comment: Can you create a working example in something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so people can see your problem and easily try to help?

Comment: Given code sample doesn't contain the 'divider' class definition and is not helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Don't blow up your list with a `divider`-element. Try this. You can easily adjust the size/height of the border that is created by using the `:after` pseudo element:

**Demo**

[Try before buy](http://jsfiddle.net/RLWEC/)

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="{% url messages_inbox %}">Inbox</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url invitations %}">Invitations</a></li>
    <li><a href="{% url notification_notices %}">All Notifications</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding 0;
    list-style: none;
}

ul > li {
    float: left;
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 30px;
    background: red;
}

ul > li:after {
    content: '';
    display:block;
    float: right;
    height: 15px;
    width: 1px;
    background: #ccc;
    margin: 7px 10px 0 10px;
}
```

**Last "border"**

To remove the border from the last element, this CSS rule does the job:

```
ul > li:last-child:after {
    content: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `border` lengths will always be >= element's width/height, so you cannot set it to 50% or anything. See the box model: http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

If you want to style those separation bars, suggest using a background image.

```
.divider {
    background: transparent url('link/to/separator.gif') right center no-repeat;
    padding: auto 10px;
}
```

This will add separater image to the right of all the links with `divider` class. For the last item in the list, you don't need to apply the class.